# How to make relation between two control using knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

i have one drop down with data and i want when drop down data will be changed then drop down text should be populated in div. i have done but code not working as per expectation.

### Full Code

```
<select data-bind="options: items, 
optionsText: 'name', 
optionsValue: 'id',
value: selectedItem"></select>

<div data-bind="text: selectedItem"></div>
Name : <div data-bind="text: selectedItem().name"></div>

function Item(id, name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}


var viewModel = {
    selectedItem: ko.observable(),
    items: ko.observableArray([new Item(1, "pencil"),
                               new Item(2, "pen"),
                               new Item(3, "marker"),
                               new Item(4, "crayon")]),
    name:ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.selectedItem(3);
}, 1000);
```

i want when user select pen or pencil then the word pen or pencil text should be displayed by div. where i made the mistake for which i am not getting my output.
thanks

### EDIT

i have one basic question because i am new in knockoutjs. when we bind drop down with below code....so then what
happen ?

```
<select data-bind="options: items, 
optionsText: 'name', 
optionsValue: 'id',
value: selectedItem"></select>
```

1) `options: items`
it means whatever stored in item that will be `datasource for dropdown`.....am i right ?

2) `optionsText: 'name',` 
   it means display only name from `datasource`.....am i right ?

3) `optionsValue: 'id'`
   it means id will be stored as value for internal use.....am i right ?

4) `value: selectedItem`
   it means selected data will be stored in `selectedItem`.

suppose i am showing employee name as `drodown` text and employee id as `drodown` value then when user

select any employee name then that employee name with id will be stored in `selectedItem` property.......am i right ?

please guide me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you told the `select` binding to use the `id` property as the `optionsValue`, so only the ID of each item is stored in `selectedItem`, rather than then `Item` itself.  If you remove that, and update the first div to bind to `selectedItem().id`, it works as expected:

```js
function Item(id, name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}


var viewModel = {
    selectedItem: ko.observable(),
    items: ko.observableArray([new Item(1, "pencil"),
                               new Item(2, "pen"),
                               new Item(3, "marker"),
                               new Item(4, "crayon")]),
    name:ko.observable()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

setTimeout(function() {
    viewModel.selectedItem(viewModel.items()[2]);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, 
optionsText: 'name', 
value: selectedItem"></select>

<div data-bind="text: selectedItem().id"></div>
Name : <div data-bind="text: selectedItem().name"></div>
```

Regarding your edit:

1 & 2 - yes.  With 3:  When you specify the `optionsValue` for the `select` binding, it means that when an item is selected, knockout will use the value of the property specified in `optionsValue` (the ID in your case) as the actual value for the select list.  This is then pushed to the observable you've specified in the `value` option.

4: The *value* of the select list will be stored in the observable specified by the `value` option.  What that *value* is is defined by the options specified in the `select` binding.  As in 3 above, if you've told knockout to use a specific property of the objects that are bound, that is what will be stored.  In your example, the numeric ID is what was going in, so you had no link to the `name` property to display in your second div.  If you don't specify the `optionsValue`, the actual item object selected is assigned to the value, meaning you can access all of the properties elsewhere.

Comment: hope u noticed that this line `viewModel.selectedItem(3);` stop working. by that line i was selecting data by id. so tell me how to do the same. thanks

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, missed that bit - have updated it now.  It reads the actual `Item` from the view model and sets the `selectedItem` to it.

Comment: i am new in knockoutjs and so still i have many confusion. so i asked few questions. please have a look at my edit section. if possible please see and answer which can drive out my confusion. thanks

Comment: if i do specify `optionsValue: 'id',` does it means when user select data from dropdown then value part only will store in selectedItem or if we do not specify optionsValue in binding time....does it means  when user select data from dropdown then dropdown text and value both will store in selectedItem property ? please rectify me if i am wrong. thanks

Comment: @Thomas Have edited my answer to cover off your points - does that clear it up?

Comment: yes bit understand and will ask u again. just tell me `<select data-bind="options: items, 
optionsText: 'name', 
optionsValue: 'id',
value: selectedItem"></select>`  `optionsValue is id` means when user select any data from dropdown then selected id will be stored in selectedItem..........am i right ?

Comment: Yes, only the ID will be stored with those options.